# Include PHP Scripts which run functions?

Tags: php

I am looking to create a plugin manager like program which starts a loop that searches for .php files in the 'plugins' folder. I need this to somehow run a function called `main()` in each file which will then run other functions. How could i accomplish this without the other `main()` functions clashing and would there be any better alternative?

Comment: A better alternative, probably. What is exactly that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: You don't list what version of PHP, but i would suggest the use of Namespacing.

Comment: What i'm trying to create is a Paypal IPN like system which when it receives a request it can do whatever is included in plugins. for example, function main{ mail () } etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use functions then you can namespace them. But for something like this id use classes. for example each plugin might have a `PluginConfiguration` class which could either be namespaced like `PluginName\PluginConfiguration` or faked like `PluginName_PluginConfiguration`.

Then you could jsut instatiate these classes and invoke whatever for example:

```
class MyCool_Plugin implements PluginInterface {

  // note the interface wouldnt be absolutely necessary, 
  // but making an interface or abstract class for this would be a good idea
  // that way you can enforce a contractual API on the configuration classes

  public function __construct() {
     // do whatever here
  }

  public function main() {
     // do whatever here
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

> By the way, what would 'PluginInterface' include?

Well an interface defines all methods (functions) a class **must** implement. You can use it to enforce a minimum API on any class the `implements` that interface. From your description this would be the method `main` although during development you may find that you need/want to add more.

```
Interface PluginInterface {

   public function main();

}
```

You can also use type hinting to enforce a specific method signature. For example lets say you always want to inject the `Application` instance thats loading the plugin into the plugin itself so it can register things or set up additional stuff. In that case you might do:

```
Interface PluginInterface {

   public function main(Application $app);

}
```

Comment: By the way, what would 'PluginInterface' include?